# Does FirebaseAuth getIdToken ever change for a user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

My users will use FirebaseAuth to get their id token, then send this to the server, where it’s authenticated with `verifyIdToken`. Currently, I’m using the uid property of the result as a key in my db. To make things more efficient, I would like to hash the id token, and use that as a key in my db instead. For this to work, `getIdToken` must always return the same thing for any given user. Can I rely on this to be true?

To clarify, the user will still be authenticated with `verifyIdToken` at first. But once they’re in the db, I will just use a query on the db to authenticate them instead.

Answer (score 0):

ID tokens expire after one hour (for security reasons) and are refreshed automatically by the Firebase client SDK.  If you want to pass an ID token to your backend, you should only pass a fresh token, otherwise it will not validate on your backend when you go to [verify it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).  I suggest reading that linked documentation to get more details, including how to use a listener to get the token immediately when it's refreshed.